# Why is Flutter installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

I have a Flutter app targeting Android SDK 34 with minimum SDK 28:

```
flutter.compileSdkVersion=34
flutter.minSdkVersion=28
flutter.targetSdkVersion=34
```

I've added below to my `build.gradle` as per [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/build-tools#groovy)

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"
    ...
}
```

`Android SDK Build-tools` version 34 is installed, but when I uninstall version 30.0.3 using Android Studio SDK manager, Flutter installs it on the next build.

> Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses License for package
> Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted. Preparing "Install Android
> SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)". "Install Android SDK
> Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" ready. Installing Android SDK
> Build-Tools 30.0.3 in
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3 "Install
> Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" complete. "Install
> Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" finished.

[image: SDK manager]

Why is Flutter installing old version of build tools and is it using the latest version of build tools as configured in Gradle?

Comment: I am not a flutter expert but in other flutter posts there were messages from flutter tools that indicate flutter is only compatible with some specific build tools versions. So my guess is that flutter simply uses the latest compatible versions and overrides your settings.

Answer (score 2):

Seems this is a known issue with Flutter. Good news is that it only downloads the old version, but it actually does use the configured one in the build.

More info on [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83573)